# How to animate map padding in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate top map padding of a view programmatically but I have no idea how to do this.

```
private GoogleMap map;
map.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Anyone have an idea how to animate `top` padding value from say 0 to 100 ?

Answer (score 16):

The map padding is not a view property nor a object property. You can test it by giving a padding to the map view:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

The result is that the map itself is padded which is different from

```
 map.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

`setPadding` is a method that offsets the UI controls inside the map. There is no property to animate. Luckily android offers the [**ValueAnimator**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator). Your problem can be solved this way:

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, paddingBottom);
animation.setDuration(150);
animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        getMap().setPadding(0, 0, 0, Integer.parseInt(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString()));
    }
});
animation.start();
```

This basically animates an integer from 0 to paddingBottom without any context. You create the context in the onAnimationUpdate listener where you assign the animated padding value to the map padding.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for that.

Comment: Can you give a link to any tutorial for that.

Comment: I was just studying Property Animation but I came to know that it requires api level 11 or later and I am designing this app to work from api level 8 and beyond. Seems like I have to drop the animation idea for my app.

Comment: Or just check the API level, that way the newer users get the benefit!

Comment: How can I check for API level and then trigger the animation ?

Answer (score 1):

```
final int newTopMargin = <value>;
Animation anim = new Animation() {

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LayoutParams params = yourView.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin = (int)(newTopMargin * interpolatedTime);
        yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};

yourView.startAnimation(anim);
```

You can achieve the animation as described above, it won't be for padding though but it will set the margin with the animation effect you want.

Comment: There is no method called `startAnimation(anim)` for `map` which is an object of `GoogleMap` class.

Comment: @Rakesh This is not a feature of map, its for the layout on which you inflate the map object i.e. which will either be a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: But I want to animate the padding of the map object so that its zoom controls are placed wherever I want. Changing the padding of its parent layout won't help me.

Answer (score -2):

It's actually very simple to animate the padding changes without having to animate manually.

Right after setting the paddings, call

```
gooleMap.animateChanges(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(Bounds, padding));
```

or any of the CameraUpdateFactory helper methods.

It is easier and also much smoother than using a ValueAnimator, especially if you animate multiple padding sides.

Comment: I couldn't find the `animateChanges` method in `googleMap`